# Как улучшить свою дикцию?

Tags: орфоэпия

Я часто запинаюсь, иногда плохо произношу букву ш, чаще всего когда она стоит в конце "делаеШ, прыгаеШь, читаеШь" также плохо получается слог ШИ-(ШЫ).

Если вас не затруднит, пожалуйста, напишите как научиться правильно произносить эти звуки. Или просто киньте ссылку на сайт

Заранее благодарен!

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Comment: Я бы пошел к логопеду, они работают и со взрослыми. Для вдохновения рекомендую вам посмотреть фильм "Король говорит", он о том, как будущий, а затем настоящий король Великобритании занимался с логопедом.

Answer (score 5):

Владислав, сайт по душе Вы сможете выбрать себе сами, а мы Вас сориентируем:

то, что Вы ищете, называется

**чистоговорки на шипящие** (в пару к Ш обычно предлагают "почистить" Ж).

Ещё лучше - послушать дикторские видео.

---

**Чистоговорки на автоматизацию шипящих звуков**

***[Автоматизация Ш в обратных слогах](http://detckiicad.ucoz.ru/publ/dlja_roditelej/ch_shh_sh_zh/chistogovorki_na_avtomatizaciju_shipjashhikh_zvukov/25-1-0-142)***

> Аш - аш - аш- вот у Даши карандаш.
>
> Ош - ош - ош — у меня есть нож.
>
> Уш - уш - уш — прими, Миша, душ.
>
> Ыш - ыш - ыш — бежит мышь.
>
> Аш-аш-аш — У Паши шалаш.
>
> Ош-ош-ош — У Миши ковш.
>
> Уш - уш - уш — у нас живёт уж.
>
> Аш-аш-аш — я точу карандаш.
>
> Аш-аш-аш — вот и домик наш.
>
> Уш-уш-уш — принимаем душ.
>
> Уш-уш-уш — я люблю холодный душ.
>
> Ыш-ыш-ыш — у Кати камыш.
>
> Еш-еш-еш — яблоки поешь.
>
> Иш - иш - иш — почему молчишь?

С чистоговорками не надо частить (в отличие от скороговорок).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]